# Terraform "aws_cloudformation_stack" has no Stack-Description

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My problem is this: I am generating a CF stack with Terraform. This works perfectly, unfortunately a stack description does not appear in the CF console as expected. What can be the reason?

This is my terraform code:

```
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "mycert" {
  name = join("-", [local.cluster_values.app_name, local.cluster_values.environment, local.service_name])

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  parameters = {
    DomainName = "${var.cname}"
  }

  template_body = <<STACK
{
 "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09", 
 "Description" : "Made with love by ****", 
 "Parameters" : {
    "DomainName" : {
      "Type" : "String",
      "Default" : "foo.***-***.***.**.**",
      "Description" : "Enter the domain name for which the ssl-cert should be issued."
    }
  }, 
 "Resources" : {
  "ACMCertificate": {
    "Type": "AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate",
    "Properties": {
      "DomainName": { "Ref" : "DomainName" },
      "DomainValidationOptions": [
        {
          "DomainName": { "Ref" : "DomainName" },
          "ValidationDomain": "**.**"
        }
      ],
      "ValidationMethod": "EMAIL"
      }
    }
  },
"Outputs" : {
    "ARN" : {
      "Description" : "SSL-Cert ARN",
      "Value" : { "Ref" : "ACMCertificate" }
      }
    }
  }  
STACK
}
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: "description does not appear in the CF console as expected" - is not specific. What exactly is happening? It should appear where?

Comment: @Marcin In the AWS console at the Cloudformation Service. There is the stack overview in which all the stacks appear with their descriptions. This one has no description although I have given one.

Comment: Your template is fine. There is no reason why it woudn't have description. Maybe you are looking at different code then in the question.

Comment: Also make sure you are using latest version of TF and aws latest aws provider.

Comment: I am using the latest versions, unfortunately no stack description is displayed, as if it is not used at all. Maybe a bug in Terraform?

Comment: It works normally. Its not a bug. Maybe your question is not fully representative of your issue then.